# chrome app, css inside iframe

Tags: css, google-chrome-app

I have an chrome app,with and iframe inside

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body >
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <iframe id="iframe" src="home.html" frameborder="0" height="150%" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in web is loading, but when it is called from index in the chrome app ,bootstrap-theme.css is not loading

I've tried too adding  type="text/css" , but neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.css">`

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

solution:

as @SaucedApples said but without the dot.

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"   />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should allow this files to be appended at the manifest.json, something like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://test-website.com/*"], 
      "js": ["js/content-script.js"],
      "css" : ["yourcss.css"]
    }
],
```

Comment: It is an app, not an extension